# jquery - get a value in mix radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery

Would you like to check what wrong in my code, I have 2 group radio button when I click the radio button variable r not have a value :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var s = 0;
    var l = 0;
    var r = 0;

    $('input[type=radio][name="saverity"]').change(function() {
        s = $(this).val();
        console.log(s);
    });

    $('input[type=radio][name="likehood"]').change(function() {
        l = $(this).val();
        console.log(l);
    });

    r = s * l;
    console.log(r);

});
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you add a working snippet instead of code blocks ?

Comment: So you add an event listener to your inputs, which is .change(). but your script executes on document.ready. in your script, all that happens with the input fields is the event listener being added - the code afterwards won't execute after the initial load- with the variables still set as 0.

You have to return your value and execute the code in a seperate function. apply event listeners on document.ready, then create a seperate calculator function and call that on input.change()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var s = 0;
    var l = 0;
    var r = 0;

    $('input[type=radio][name="saverity"]').change(function() {
        s = $(this).val();
      recalculate();
    });

    $('input[type=radio][name="likehood"]').change(function() {
        l = $(this).val();
        recalculate();
    });
    
    function recalculate(){
        r = s * l;
        console.log(r);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
  Saverity
  <input type="radio" name="saverity" value="0">
  <input type="radio" name="saverity" value="1">
</label>
<br>
<label>
  Likehood
  <input type="radio" name="likehood" value="0">
  <input type="radio" name="likehood" value="1">
</label>
```